# File read Python - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
def compare():
        file1=open("Rules.txt")
        for rules in file1:
            rule = rules.split(",")
            break
        membersFile=open("Members.txt")
        for members in membersFile:
            member = members.split(',')
            break
        print (rule[0] + "," +member[1] + ","+ rule[1] + "," +member[2] + ","+  rule[2] + "," + member[3])
        if (rule[0]<=member[1]) and (rule[1]<=member[2]) and (rule[2]==member[  3]):
            print (member[0] + " is Continued")
        else:
            print (member[0] + " is Discontinued")
compare()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
print (rule[0] + "," +member[1] + ","+ rule[1] + "," +member[2] + ","+  rule[2] + "," + member[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: well... considering the 2 break instruction i think you assume that rule and member are vector containing the rules in first line and the member in first file line which were comma separated.

it is hard to guess what the problem is if you do not provide us the content of the input files

Comment: I Can't understand ...Please explain me clearly.Rules.txt Follow as        Age     Win-Loss Log-in Gender Income Status
-----------------------------------------------------------
GE,25 GE,8  - Male - Continue
GE,25 LT,8  - Male - Discontinue
GE,25 -  - Female - Discontinue
LT,25 -  GE,150 - - Continue
LT,25 GE,5  LT,150 - - Continue
LT,25 LT,5  LT,150 - - Discontinue

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read the file.  Some thing like this:

```
def compare():
        with open("Rules.txt") as file1:
            for rules in file1.readlines():  // <-note readlines()
                rule = rules.split(",")
                break
        with open("Members.txt") as membersFile:
            for members in membersFile.readlines():  // <-here too
                member = members.split(',')
                break
        print (rule[0] + "," +member[1] + ","+ rule[1] + "," +member[2] + ","+  rule[2] + "," + member[3])
        if (rule[0]<=member[1]) and (rule[1]<=member[2]) and (rule[2]==member[  3]):
            print (member[0] + " is Continued")
        else:
            print (member[0] + " is Discontinued")
```

But actually, the `break` statements also seem to certainly be wrong, and possibly the `split(",")` also - as in the comments - really need a properly formmatted sample of the input, and a better description of the expected behavior.